# How to bind view's loaded event to a method in the view model in WP7.1

Tags: .net, silverlight, mvvm, command, windows-phone-7.1

I want to process a Page_Loaded event of my View (`PhoneApplicationPage`) in a view model. This used to be accomplished by the following:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="Loaded">
            <Command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding LoadedCommand}" />
        </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

This approach uses MVVM Light `EventToCommand`.

But his approach no longer works and gives the following error:

> A value of type 'EventToCommand' cannot be added to a collection or
>   dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'.

In WP7.1, what is the correct MVVM way to bind view's events to a view model's methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [InvokeCommandAction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff724018%28v=Expression.40%29.aspx).

Update

Actually if you just want it to directly bind to the method you can also try CallMethodAction. ;)